# Rendering problems and ImageView

Tags: android, android-appcompat, src, aapt, aapt2

When i create new project in Android. I'm getting errors:

1. Rendering Problem (`activity_main`)
2. Command **Aapt2.exe** with non-zero exit code value 1
3. `ImageView srcCompat` Error.

What should i do?

Comment: improved formatting, added android tag

Answer (score 0):

Use AppComapatImageView instead of ImageView

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_icon" />
```

add this in gradle.[refer this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources#vector-drawables-backward-solution)

```html
android {
   defaultConfig {
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
 }
```